# Webhooks testing inconsistencies whilst debugging using Stripe CLI and event triggers

Tags: php, webhooks, stripe-payments

The problem is that if I trigger the same event multiple times, I get different results.

I have *three terminals* open:

1. **Listening** using:

```
   listen --forward-to localhost:8888/my-endpoint.php
```

2. **Triggering** using

```
    stripe trigger + event
```

(eg. stripe trigger payment_intent.succeeded)

3. **Logging** errors from localhost

**Troubleshooting**

- I can trigger by running through the Stripe checkout too. Checkout works, but results in terminal are similar to described.
- I have also run the trigger whilst xdebug is listening and can see the code steps through in the exact fashion expected (ie assigns simple text responses to the body and calls 200/400 codes).

**Important notes**

The screenshot below shows log (left), listen (top right) and event trigger (bottom right).

(1st and 4th attempts work. 2nd and 3rd do not. They do not include logs or:

```
2020-04-24 16:17:16   --> payment_intent.succeeded [evt_1GbMikFOnngxtrI1EfZyfaNo]
2020-04-24 16:17:16  <--  [200] POST http://localhost:8888/scripts/stripe/webhook-endpoint.php [evt_1GbMikFOnngxtrI1EfZyfaNo]
```

Note you can see the timecodes of the different events in the top right.

And the log only gets updated once, on the first trigger.

The other fun thing is that sometimes the responses appear in the Stripe dashboard, sometimes they don't.

Any ideas?

[image: screenshots of 3 terminals]

Webhooks Code (signature and api keys are set above but hidden here)

```
$payload = @file_get_contents('php://input'); //get json POST data stripe sends
$sig_header = $_SERVER['HTTP_STRIPE_SIGNATURE'];
$event = null;

try {
    $event = \Stripe\Webhook::constructEvent(
      $payload, $sig_header, $endpoint_secret, //get data
    );
  } catch(\UnexpectedValueException $e) {
    // Invalid payload
    printf("Invalid payload");
    http_response_code(400);
    exit();
  } catch(\Stripe\Exception\SignatureVerificationException $e) {
    // Invalid signature
    printf("Invalid signature.");
    http_response_code(400);
    exit();
  }
// Handle the event(s)
switch ($event->type) {
    case 'checkout.session.completed': 
        $session = $event->data->object;
        printf("Checkout Session Completed");
        http_response_code(200); 
        break;
    case 'payment_intent.succeeded': 
        $paymentIntent = $event->data->object; 
        $intent = $event->data->object;
        printf("Payment Intent Succeeded: %s", $intent->id);
        http_response_code(200);
        error_log( json_encode( $intent, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT ) );
        break;
    case 'payment_intent.payment_failed': 
        $paymentMethod = $event->data->object;
        $intent = $event->data->object;
        $error_message = $intent->last_payment_error ? $intent->last_payment_error->message : "";
        printf("Failed: %s, %s", $intent->id, $error_message);
        http_response_code(200);
        break;
    case 'payment_intent.processing':
        printf("Payment Intent Processing: %s", $intent->id);
        http_response_code(200);
        break;
    case 'payment_intent.canceled': 
        printf("Payment Intent canceled: %s", $intent->id);
        http_response_code(200);
        break;
    default:
        http_response_code(400);
        exit();
}

http_response_code(200);
return false;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I've understood correctly, my apologies if I'm off the point here.

I think that the issue here is that using `stripe trigger payment_intent.succeeded` ultimately creates 3 events:

- `payment_intent.created`
- `charge.succeeded`
- `payment_intent.succeeded`

It seems that the case statement doesn't have clauses for the first two event types so they default to 400s.

Depending on what you would like to do, you could extend the case statement to handle those events. Also maybe this is relevant to your findings, but Events do not have a guaranteed ordering, this is normal behaviour and something that you have to keep in mind when building your system [0]. Hope this helps!

[0] https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks/best-practices#event-ordering

Comment: This is a good point! I wonder if throwing 400's does something spooky. I'll test it and get back to this thread in the near future.

Comment: It works! Excellent analysis, thank you so much. I assume this won't be a problem when live because you choose the events stripe sends in the dashboard, but it seems to be necessary here. I can sleep easy now...

Comment: Exactly, you have complete control over which events you see. Glad it worked!